# How to work with individual frames of a MovieClip for button skinning

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, air

I need to skin a Flex button using a MovieClip exported as .swf from Flash Professional.  Most of the instructions online say that I need to do something along these lines:

```
  [Embed(source='Button.swf', symbol="AudioButtonDown")]
  public var Down:Class;
  [Embed(source='Button.swf', symbol="AudioButtonOver")]
  public var Over:Class;
  [Embed(source='Button.swf', symbol="AudioButtonNormal")]
  public var Normal:Class;

  ...

  Button1.setStyle('overSkin',Over);
  Button1.setStyle('downSkin',Down);
  Button1.setStyle('upSkin',Normal);
```

Which works great if each frame of the movieclip could have it's own symbol.  But what I have is a single movieclip with 3 frames, and a single symbol "AudioButton", and when I try to apply it as a skin, the three frames just play over and over again in an endless loop.  How can I divvy up the frames of a loaded swf, and apply frame 1 to "upSkin" frame 2 to "overSkin", etc...?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Why would you ever use Flash Pro to skin a Flex button?!

Comment: I wouldn't.  It is a requirement of my employer, who wants an air application created from existing flash graphics, and his flash guy is too lazy to save the assets as .png

Comment: But too lazy to create separate symbols for each button state? that's a bit much don't you think?

Comment: Since I haven't worked with Flash Professional before, I'm not sure what's standard - from everything I'm reading online, it's pretty much necessary to create separate symbols for each button state, if the goal is to make flex skins.  If you can confirm that, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating symbols for each state would be the easiest way to go, but not the only one (however, the symbol approach is the one you should use).

Another way to do it would be to just set the skin as the one symbol and from there do `yourSymbol.goToAndStop('someButtonState')`.  This is strongly discouraged before Flex doesn't work with frames and it could have adverse effects.

Comment: Is there any way to apply a symbol to individual frames of a movieclip in Flash Professional?  Or is he going to have to separate out each frame into it's own MovieClip in order to give each one a symbol?

Comment: the latter.  It's the only way to associate a symbol.